# "Running Product" aggregate/ windowed function in PostgreSql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate

I am trying to normalize End-of-Day stock prices in PostgreSql.

Let's say I have a stock table defined as such:

```
create table eod (
  date date not null,
  stock_id int not null,
  split decimal(16,8) not null,
  close decimal(12,6) not null,
  constraint pk_eod primary key (date, stock_id)
);
```

Data in this table might look like this:

```
"date","stock_id","eod_split","close"
"2014-06-13",14010920,"1.00000000","182.560000"
"2014-06-13",14010911,"1.00000000","91.280000"
"2014-06-13",14010923,"1.00000000","41.230000"
"2014-06-12",14010911,"1.00000000","92.290000"
"2014-06-12",14010920,"1.00000000","181.220000"
"2014-06-12",14010923,"1.00000000","40.580000"
"2014-06-11",14010920,"1.00000000","182.250000"
"2014-06-11",14010911,"1.00000000","93.860000"
"2014-06-11",14010923,"1.00000000","40.860000"
"2014-06-10",14010911,"1.00000000","94.250000"
"2014-06-10",14010923,"1.00000000","41.110000"
"2014-06-10",14010920,"1.00000000","184.290000"
"2014-06-09",14010920,"1.00000000","186.220000"
"2014-06-09",14010911,"7.00000000","93.700000"
"2014-06-09",14010923,"1.00000000","41.270000"
"2014-06-06",14010923,"1.00000000","41.480000"
"2014-06-06",14010911,"1.00000000","645.570000"
"2014-06-06",14010920,"1.00000000","186.370000"
"2014-06-05",14010920,"1.00000000","185.980000"
"2014-06-05",14010911,"1.00000000","647.350000"
"2014-06-05",14010923,"1.00000000","41.210000"
... 
"2005-03-04",14010920,"1.00000000","92.370000"
"2005-03-04",14010911,"1.00000000","42.810000"
"2005-03-04",14010923,"1.00000000","25.170000"
"2005-03-03",14010923,"1.00000000","25.170000"
"2005-03-03",14010911,"1.00000000","41.790000"
"2005-03-03",14010920,"1.00000000","92.410000"
"2005-03-02",14010920,"1.00000000","92.920000"
"2005-03-02",14010923,"1.00000000","25.260000"
"2005-03-02",14010911,"1.00000000","44.121000"
"2005-03-01",14010920,"1.00000000","93.300000"
"2005-03-01",14010923,"1.00000000","25.280000"
"2005-03-01",14010911,"1.00000000","44.500000"
"2005-02-28",14010923,"1.00000000","25.160000"
"2005-02-28",14010911,"2.00000000","44.860000"
"2005-02-28",14010920,"1.00000000","92.580000"
"2005-02-25",14010923,"1.00000000","25.250000"
"2005-02-25",14010920,"1.00000000","92.800000"
"2005-02-25",14010911,"1.00000000","88.990000"
"2005-02-24",14010923,"1.00000000","25.370000"
"2005-02-24",14010920,"1.00000000","92.640000"
"2005-02-24",14010911,"1.00000000","88.930000"
"2005-02-23",14010923,"1.00000000","25.200000"
"2005-02-23",14010911,"1.00000000","88.230000"
"2005-02-23",14010920,"1.00000000","92.100000"
...
"2003-02-24",14010920,"1.00000000","78.560000"
"2003-02-24",14010911,"1.00000000","14.740000"
"2003-02-24",14010923,"1.00000000","24.070000"
"2003-02-21",14010920,"1.00000000","79.950000"
"2003-02-21",14010923,"1.00000000","24.630000"
"2003-02-21",14010911,"1.00000000","15.000000"
"2003-02-20",14010911,"1.00000000","14.770000"
"2003-02-20",14010920,"1.00000000","79.150000"
"2003-02-20",14010923,"1.00000000","24.140000"
"2003-02-19",14010920,"1.00000000","79.510000"
"2003-02-19",14010911,"1.00000000","14.850000"
"2003-02-19",14010923,"1.00000000","24.530000"
"2003-02-18",14010923,"2.00000000","24.960000"
"2003-02-18",14010911,"1.00000000","15.270000"
"2003-02-18",14010920,"1.00000000","79.330000"
"2003-02-14",14010911,"1.00000000","14.670000"
"2003-02-14",14010920,"1.00000000","77.450000"
"2003-02-14",14010923,"1.00000000","48.300000"
"2003-02-13",14010920,"1.00000000","75.860000"
"2003-02-13",14010911,"1.00000000","14.540000"
"2003-02-13",14010923,"1.00000000","46.990000"
```

Note the "split" column.  When a split value other than 1 is recorded, it basically means that the stock shares split by that factor.  IOW, when the split is 2.0, the number of the outstanding shares doubled, but the value of each individual share is halved from that point on.  If the stock was worth $100 per share, it's now worth $50 per share.

If you graph this with raw numbers, this sort of thing is truly ugly.  Sharp cliffs show up, when the overall value of the company did not significantly change... and when you have multiple splits, you end up with a graph that does not properly reflect the trending of the company, often by a large margin.  In the above example, where there was a 2:1 split, your close prices for a stock would look something like 100, 100, 100, 50, 50, 50.

I want to use this table to create a "normalized" price, in a reasonably efficient manner (there's quite a few records to chunk through).  Continuing the sample, this would show the stock prices at 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50.  If there were multiple splits, the data should still be consistent and smooth, if we ignored actual market value changes.

My idea is, if I can create a CTE of a "running product" aggregate of the split value, going back in time, I can define date ranges per stock and what the modifier value to apply to the closing cost should be, then join that back to the eod table and select into a new table the adjusted close value for each stock.

...the problem is, I cannot wrap my head around how to do that in anything other than a whole bunch of temp tables and multi-step processes.  I do not know of any built-in functionality to make this easier, either.

Can someone show me how I can generate the normalized data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need a CTE.  You just need a cumulative product.  Postgres doesn't have one built in.  But, arithmetic to the rescue!

```
select eod.*,
       exp(sum(ln(eod_split)) over (partition by stock_id order by date)) as cume_split,
       (close *
        exp(sum(ln(eod_split)) over (partition by stock_id order by date))
       ) as normalized_price
from eod;
```

Comment: That's not arithmetic.  That's rocket science.  I don't even understand what's going on here, but I will try it out and see if I can make sense of it.

Comment: Looks like this works.  I'll need more time to understand what it does, but it's nice and neat and performant.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: This answer is purely gold!  Wracking my head how to solve a similar problem & the simplicity of this deserves +1000 more points :). 
Awesome book btw, Gordon!

Answer (score 1):

Hilarious, looking for this solution, I find that an associate already asked about it.  Here is the basic algebra behind this ingenious solution:  https://blog.prepscholar.com/natural-log-rules